# How can I load an Emacs capture template into an open file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Please excuse my newness to Emacs Lisp. I started using org-mode and love it. In my workflow, I am trying to load a template into an open buffer or prompt the template to ask for a location to where the file is to be saved.

For example, I have a 'meetings' template. When I call that template, I would like to be prompted for a filename and then the template will be loaded into that file and file will be loaded in Emacs.

How can I do this within Emacs?

Comment: I think `%:file` should work for file prompt, but I didn't try. I didn't even know this feature existed. I'll try tomorrow if you won't figure it out by then. The entire list is here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html#Template-expansion

Comment: To those who voted the question to be put on hold and to prevent this question from being closed or moved: The question is 100% legitimate, however deals with some less known feature of `org-mode`, and is an interesting question at that. Follow the link from the previous comment to find out about capture templates. The linked info will also make the question clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with so far:

```
(defun caputre-create-meeting-link ()
  (let ((new-file (read-file-name "Save meeting info in ")))
    (run-with-timer 1 nil (eval `(lambda () (find-file ,new-file))))
     (format "[[%s]]" new-file)))

(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("a" "Insert a link to meeting" plain
         (file "~/org/notes.org")
         "Meeting info: %(caputre-create-meeting-link)"
         :immediate-finish t)))
```

to more or less get the effect you describe. But you probably could simply substitute `%(capture-create-meeting-link)` with `%^L` and then <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> on the link to open it.

Comment: Thanks wvxvw for the help and direction. My question is probably simpler than that. What I ended up doing is using the buffer-name variable to load the template into an open buffer(I still wanted the template function to ask me for the filename but got errors so I am settling for this): `(setq org-capture-templates '(("m" "Template for capturing meeting minutes" plain (file (buffer-name)) "%[c:/org-templates/meeting-template.org]" :immediate-finish t)))` In the template itself, I am using using prompts for title and attendees, etc.